# Google places API not returning address components

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

My program is trying to determine the City, state, and country based on some text, for example "New york yankee stadium" I want to get New york city, NY, USA. I am using Google places API to do this. According to the documentations, the API should return a list of address component https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details. However, right now its only returning formatted address "1 E 161st St, Bronx, NY 10451, United States".

here is my web service url
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=MY_KEY&query=new%20york%20yankee%20stadium

Anyone familiar with google places API that can let me know if I am not writting the right query or parameter?

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "1 E 161st St, Bronx, NY 10451, United States",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.82964260000001,
               "lng" : -73.9261745
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.83279975,
                  "lng" : -73.92236575000001
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.82643674999999,
                  "lng" : -73.93052034999999
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "3d78036d61d35f48650bda737226432b57d82511",
         "name" : "Yankee Stadium",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 540,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101696810905045719819/photos\"\u003eYankee Stadium\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAIxmCLrNS_XZ2FcJqVvRVtBUlNYMBVTVKppOWBu7sICj2q70cqJARBoJlTcZpydbMTzURKWWMVJhYpVCqsnia5pjmDhjvjsTirrEnAc6gvmRYKuUwgewB9Re--FulXzXZ5DY3P9fkwIwuc4U9BJVbqHD5O-N6SbbHcqn4XHUj_OdEhCoNPZ3kiNJhxOCGdYG5O4DGhTqVfUjdq7JzasqYATvQxkL1-H3xg",
               "width" : 1242
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJcWnnWiz0wokRCB6aVdnDQEk",
         "rating" : 4.4,
         "reference" : "CmRRAAAA5dHiw1YmLxW60_jITBZjMiUs48L4aVUqlPnPDpN_ySa7rw8kPp04WWk0qf8mG-kkMFSNzh39lP0YwfynW54tLcY4s_EYbAPvNWTMe6wXHm_FJiVbI0Lfenyxz4yOTzunEhDgI64EWoXkQe9k45y6qP3-GhSVSdCMPPZA3joFbnYGV-bqo2e0lw",
         "types" : [ "stadium", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. In my case it's returning some address components but not street number or street name.

Comment: Did you try to add a filter type with all response fields you want from your request?

Answer (score 1):

Its a two step process, first search and get the place_id from google places search service,

use the returned place_id and pass it with another call to receive the individual address components,

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJcWnnWiz0wokRCB6aVdnDQEk&key=

```
{"html_attributions": [],
"result": {
"address_components": [
{
"long_name": "1",
"short_name": "1",
"types": [
"street_number"
]
},
{
"long_name": "East 161st Street",
"short_name": "E 161st St",
"types": [
"route"
]
},
{
"long_name": "Concourse",
"short_name": "Concourse",
"types": [
"neighborhood",
"political"
]
},
{
"long_name": "Bronx",
"short_name": "Bronx",
"types": [
"sublocality_level_1",
"sublocality",
"political"
]
},
{
"long_name": "Bronx County",
"short_name": "Bronx County",
"types": [
"administrative_area_level_2",
"political"
]
},
```